# List.Clear() is not working

Tags: c#

```
private Map GetMinMaxDistanceShcoolData(Map MonitorsData)
{
    var tempData = MonitorsData.MonitorsDataList;

    if (tempData != null)
    {
        foreach (var monitor in tempData)
        {
            foreach (var tehsil in monitor.Tehsils)
            {
                var ordered = tehsil.Schools.OrderBy(x => x.Distance).ToList();
                var min = ordered.FirstOrDefault();
                var max = ordered.LastOrDefault();

                ordered.ToList().Clear();

                tehsil.Schools.ToList().Add(min);
                tehsil.Schools.ToList().Add(max);
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Before and After clearing the list the count of the list is same.
Even when I am using the Remove() instead of Clear(), it is also not removing the list.
Also the Add(min) and Add(max) is not working.

Comment: `ToList()` *may* generate new lists. You seem to have sprinkled it rather liberally throughout your code.

Comment: `ToList` is a loop that fills another `List<T>` with the items of the source-sequence. You are not even storing this list somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

It's working just fine, you're just calling one many ToList

ordered is a List, then you call ToList (creating a new List), then you clear that last List (not touching the first one).

What you wrote :

```
ordered.ToList().Clear();
```

Is the same as

```
var newlist = ordered.ToList();
newlist.Clear(); // of course this doesn't clear ordered
```

What you need to do is simply

```
ordered.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the wrong thing. ToList creates a new List, therefore `Ordered` is a new list, and you clear that, but not the orginal data.

```
 ordered.ToList().Clear();
```

Also `ordered` is already a list, calling `ToList` is redundant

I think you meant to do this:

```
var ordered = tehsil.Schools.OrderBy(x => x.Distance).ToList();
var min = ordered.FirstOrDefault();
var max = ordered.LastOrDefault();

tehsil.Schools.Clear();

tehsil.Schools.Add(min);
tehsil.Schools.Add(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `ToList()` call before `Clear()`

```
var tempData = MonitorsData.MonitorsDataList;

if (tempData != null)
{
    foreach (var monitor in tempData)
    {
        foreach (var tehsil in monitor.Tehsils)
        {
            var ordered = tehsil.Schools.OrderBy(x => .Distance).ToList();
            var min = ordered.FirstOrDefault();
            var max = ordered.LastOrDefault();

            ordered.Clear();

            tehsil.Schools.ToList().Add(min);
            tehsil.Schools.ToList().Add(max);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @CallumLinington It's a type of `List<T>` since ordered if you take a look is a `List<T>`. And `List<T>` does have a `Clear()` method

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ordered.ToList().Clear();` with `ordered.Clear();`

Answer (score 0):

You're clearing the list created by `.ToList()`

```
ordered.ToList().Clear();
// .ToList() - Creates a new list.
// .Clear() - Clears the list that was created.
```

To clear a list use:

```
ordered.Clear();
// .Clear() - Clears the list called ordered.
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you have a few issues here, try something like this.

```
foreach (var tehsil in monitor.Tehsils)
{
    var ordered = tehsil.Schools.OrderBy(x => x.Distance).ToList();
    if(!ordered.Any || ordered.Count < 3) continue;
    var maxmin = new List<tehsil.Schools> { ordered.FirstOrDefault(), ordered.LastOrDefault() }
    tehsil.Schools = maxmin;
}
```